# Show/hide a vue-strap spinner from parent or child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Before a component mounts, I want to show a `yuche/vue-strap` spinner because I have to load data thru an AJAX request. Then I want the spinner to hide after the request completes. The spinner is located in the parent `days.vue` template right before the `cycles.vue` template.

Here is `days.vue`:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Day ' + day.day" v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="day.id">
            <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="success">
                <panel is-open type="success" header="Cycles">
                    <spinner :ref="'cycles_spinner_' + day.id" size="xl" text="Loading cycles..."></spinner>
                    <cycles
                            :day="day"
                    >
                    </cycles>
                </panel>
            </accordion>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'plan'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                days: {}
            }
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            var self = this;

            axios.get('/plans/' + this.plan.id + '/days/data')
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.days = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is `cycles.vue`:

```
<template>
    <accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
        <panel :is-open="index === 0" type="primary" :header="'Week ' + cycle.week + ': ' + cycle.name" v-for="(cycle, index) in cycles" :key="cycle.id">
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="update">
                ....misc input fields here...
            </form>
        </panel>
    </accordion>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'day'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                cycles: []
            }
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id].show();

            axios.get('/plans/days/' + this.day.id + '/cycles/data')
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.cycles = response.data;
                    this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id].hide();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I try `this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id].show();` I get the error `Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`.

I also tried `this.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id].show();` but gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a cleaner approach than what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

[`ref`s inside `v-for`s](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) generate **arrays**. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> When `ref` is used together with `v-for`, the ref you get will be an **array** containing the child components mirroring the data source.

So instead of:

```
this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id].show();
```

You should do:

```
this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id][0].show();
```

The index is `0` because you are creating only one ref named `'cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id` per iteration.

## Inside axios promises, same issue (and beware of `this`)

Inside your axios `.then()` you'll face the same problem. Also, inside `.then(function (response) {` don't use `this`, use `self`:

```js
axios.get('/plans/days/' + this.day.id + '/cycles/data')
  .then(function(response) {
    self.cycles = response.data;
    self.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id][0].hide();
//  ^^^^---------------- changed ----------------------^^^
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: When I do `this.$parent.$refs['cycles_spinner_' + this.day.id][0].show();` I get the error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Look, I've created an example: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/50wL7mdz/227835/ see it works here? (The log prints.) Can you edit it to reproduce your error?